# jQuery/Ajax How does this website achieve this?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm looking at this site [slideone](http://themes.goodlayers.com/slideone/) and whenever you click on a link it loads the contents in the same container/div/whatever they are using. I was wondering if I could get something like this on my site but I don't know how to go about doing this. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mix of hiding and showing content.  When you interact with a link that loads another section, the following happens:

- A request is sent via ajax to the server, server sends back html.
- Fadeout parent's content and append the HTML recieved from the server into a hidden div
- Fadein new content
- Look awesome

EDIT

[Here is great link to get you started on how to do something like this really easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632756/jquery-use-letters-as-an-id/13632892#13632892)

EDIT 2:
Here is the jist of the jQuery work:

```
$(function(){
    $(".exposer").click(function(){
        var $ele = $(this);
        $ele.parent().siblings().hide('fade');
        if($(this).data('url') == undefined){
       $(this).siblings('.visContent').hide('slide')
           $(this).siblings('.hidContent').show('slide'); 
        }else{
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/echo/json',
                type: "GET",
                success:function(data){
                    var dt = new Date();
                    data = "You would have loaded HTML from " + url + ".<br /> This was loaded at " + dt;
                    //You would normally use the HTML from data to populate the html
                    //in this example a pre-built string will suffice
                    console.log(data,$ele, url);
               $ele.siblings('.visContent').hide('slide');
               $ele.siblings('.hidContent').append("<div class='ajaxload'>" + data + "</div>").addClass('ajaxload').show('slide');            
                },error:function(xhr, status){
                  alert('error loading page');
                }                    
            })
        }
    });
    $(".closer").live('click',function(){
        $(".ajaxload").hide('fade');
       var $mainp = $(this).parent().parent(); 
        $(this).parent().hide('slide');
        $(this).parent().parent().children('.visContent').show('slide');
                $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.childWrap').show('slide');
    });
});
```

​
I've created a fiddle for you to show how the basics of this would work.  [Here is the fiddle example I've built](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/XmHga/1/)

Comment: What part of the site are we talking about here? When I load the site, all the sections (blog, Portfolio, Features) are already in the DOM.

Comment: @Jeemusu I am not talking about when you first load the page, look what happens when you click on an image or a link to load the ajax content.

Comment: @TNCodeMonkey, you are completely correct, the "read more" links do load content via AJAX.

Comment: Thank you, someone kindly take away my -1 please

Comment: @Jeemusu Yes it's a big page that contains multiple section, but if you click to view blog post, or an image or something others, it get content from server via ajax request and load content in a container.

Comment: Yes and I am trying to achieve this.

Comment: @user1865179 I added a link to a great example of how to accomplish this.  Please comment if you have further questions.

Comment: Okay using those examples where do I declare where I want it to load an html file?

If I want to click a href and it load an html in it's place?

Comment: I've added an example of the basic jQuery code to get you started, and  working fiddle link to work with.

Comment: @user1865179 I've updated the code once again to include a catch to see if an element, rendered via ajax, is present before doing an ajax call to load the HTML.

Comment: See this works perfectly but the problem is what if I wanted the visContent to be the entire page and there would be multiple 'data-link's within the entire page and  when you click on one of the 'data-link's it shows content based on the data-link assigned and loads new content there?

But again this helped me get a good start and I appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @user1865179 no problem.  please make sure to accept this answer if it was able to get you going, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

[This jQuery waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) is a good place to start , it gives you the ability to monitor scrolling easily, fire ajax events at certain point, fire events to change what is selected in the menu at certain scroll points.

You could always just animate and scroll to a different point like they do in their site without having the other events happen if a simpler version is ok